# Tree-LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I would like to use a `tree-LSTM` in [keras](/questions/tagged/keras), similar to what is described in this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00075.
It is essentially similar to a **Long Short-Term Memory** network, but with a tree-like input sequence instead of a chain-like one.

I think it is a relatively standard architecture and would find uses in a lot of contexts, but I couldn't find any public [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) implementation of it. Is this something that already exists somewhere?

The closest I could find is this [torch](/questions/tagged/torch) implementation: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/treelstm, but that won't integrate well with the rest of my project.

Question is, how can I implement [**Tree-RNN**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417420310435#:%7E:text=3.2.-,Tree%20structural%20recurrent%20neural%20network%20(Tree%2DRNN),to%20implement%20network%20traffic%20classification.) or **Tree-LSTM** in [keras](/questions/tagged/keras)? FYI, it wasn't possible (AFAIK) to implement such architecture with sequential or functional API but it can be implemented in subclassed API introduced in [tensorflow2](/questions/tagged/tensorflow2), [source](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/).

Comment: Due to the fact that "tree-LSTM" is an introduced concept of the given article, clearly, there won't be a keras implementation to it. Nonetheless, you can use the code [here](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/keras-lstm-tutorial/) (also see the relevant git that he points to) to see how LSTM is handled in keras and make the necessary adaptations to it that will transform it to a "tree-LSTM" as the article states.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure what you mean by introduced concept, LSTMs are also a concept that was introduced in an article (Hochreiter & Schmidhuber, 1997), and the Tree-LSTM paper is 4 years old with almost 1000 citations so it is not a fringe object. They are substantially different from a simple LSTM as it is a recursive neural network and not a recurrent one like a LSTM.

Comment: Exactly my point. LSTM was introduced 22 years ago and has over 15,000 citations - more than an order of magnitude over tree-LSTM. If you go to the actual code of it (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2051) you will see that it was only written in 2015.

Comment: Well, the first release of keras was in 2015 so it would have been difficult to write the code much before :) But point taken, I will check back in 2033!

Comment: Why this issue is closed? This is a valid question.

Comment: Voting to re-open this question, it's valid to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a tree-LSTM in Keras using the Subclassing API. This will allow you to define your own custom layers and models by subclassing the `tf.keras.layers.Layer` and `tf.keras.Model` classes, respectively.

To implement a tree-LSTM in the Subclassing API, you will need to define a custom layer that takes a tree-structured input and applies the LSTM operation to each node in the tree. Here is some pseudocode that outlines the steps you can follow:

```
class TreeLSTMLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
    super(TreeLSTMLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.units = units

  def build(self, input_shape):
    # Define the weight matrices and biases for the LSTM operation
    # (e.g., self.W_i, self.W_f, self.W_o, self.W_c, self.b_i, etc.)
    # based on the number of units in the layer
    # (e.g., input_dim = units, output_dim = units)
    # and the input shape of the tree (i.e., input_shape[0])

  def call(self, inputs):
    # Unpack the inputs into the tree structure and the initial states
    # (e.g., tree, h_0, c_0 = inputs)

    # Initialize a list to store the output states for each node in the tree
    output_states = []

    # Recursively traverse the tree and apply the LSTM operation
    # at each node, updating the hidden and cell states as you go
    # (e.g., h_t, c_t = lstm(x_t, h_t-1, c_t-1))
    def traverse_tree(node, h_t, c_t):
      # Apply the LSTM operation to the current node
      # (e.g., i_t, f_t, o_t, g_t = lstm(x_t, h_t, c_t))
      # Update the hidden and cell states
      # (e.g., c_t = f_t * c_t + i_t * g_t, h_t = o_t * tf.tanh(c_t))
      output_states.append((h_t, c_t))
      # Recursively traverse the children of the current node
      for child in node.children:
        traverse_tree(child, h_t, c_t)

    # Start the recursive traversal at the root of the tree
    traverse_tree(tree.root, h_0, c_0)

    # Return the output states for each node in the tree
    return output_states
```

Once you have defined your custom TreeLSTMLayer, you can use it to build a tree-LSTM model by subclassing the `tf.keras.Model` class and using the TreeLSTMLayer as one of the layers in your model.

Answer (score -2):

You can flattened the input tree, and map the question into the normal use case of a flat input.

The effective solution will be the same as long as you make sure that your degrees of freedom are the same.